# Evento em elemento criado após o carregamento da DOM

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Seguinte:
Possuo uma página onde serão feitos pedidos.
Nesta página, o usuário escolhe o item e pode, caso queria, adicionar itens extras a este item, por exemplo, "mais queijo".
Quando eu insiro este "mais queijo", eu crio uma linha com duas colunasna tabela de itens extras. A primeira contém a descrição do item extra e a segunda um botão ppara deletar este item, caso necessário.
Problema:
Se eu insiro mais de um item, o evento é acionado passando como parametros o último item inserido.

```
                    id = gera_id(itemExtra[0].replace(' ', '')); // Função para não existir duplicidade de ids
                var table       = document.getElementById(tabela);
                var n_rows      = document.getElementById(tabela).rows.length;
                var row         = table.insertRow(n_rows);
                row.id          = id;
                var cell1       = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2       = row.insertCell(1);
                cell1.innerHTML = itemExtra[1];

                var deletaExtra = document.createElement("INPUT");
                deletaExtra.setAttribute("type", "button");
            /*
                deletaExtra.onclick = function (){
                    deletaItemExtra(id, tabela);
                }
            */
                var parametros = ""+id + "," + tabela+"";
                deletaExtra.addEventListener("click", function(){
                    deletaItemExtra(id, tabela);
                });

                deletaExtra.setAttribute("value", 'X');
                cell2.appendChild(deletaExtra);
```

Caso necessário, segue o link para a página completa.
http://siclopadm.com.br/sc/9/app/siclop/wbl_vendas/

Comment: Onde foi feita a declaração do `id` ?

Comment: Logo após a criação da row. Quinta linha no trecho do código

Answer (score 1):

### Versão com puro Javascript:

Primeiro criamos esta pequena função que vai separar as classes do elemento individualmente caso este tenha multiplas classes utilizando o [`.split()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp), logo em seguida utilizando o [`.indexOf()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) indicamos-lhe para começar a procura do nome da classe com o index de `-1`, que basicamente é verificar por algo que ainda não está neste grupo.

**Tem Classe?**

```
function temClasse(elem, className) {
    return elem.className.split(' ').indexOf(className) > -1;
}
```

Em seguida então vamos controlar o que se passa no evento clique.
No primeiro exemplo que postei, tinha apontado o clique para o documento mas corrigi agora apontando-o para o elemento *parent* que é uma melhor prática pois assim não estamos a verificar cliques no documento mas sim no elemento alvo que é o que nos interessa.

Quando ocorre um click no elemento *parent*, que neste caso será a classe `.container`, vamos verificar com o `if` se este clique foi no elemento alvo (*target*) com a classe `el-alvo` ou não, juntamente nesta mesma verificação do `if` iremos correr a função **temClass** para procurar por novos elementos `indexOf() > -1`.

**Clicou no elemento alvo?**

```
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (temClasse(e.target, 'el-alvo')) {
        alert(e.target.id);
    }
});
```

Recapitulando esta parte, sempre que ocorrer um clique no `.container`, `=>` if/se este clique foi num elemento `child` com a classe `.el-alvo` juntamente verifica também se existem novos elementos `=>` faz alguma coisa.

### Exemplo:

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container');

// Código abaixo não interessa. Apenas para criar novos elementos
document.getElementById('add-el').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var el = document.createElement('li');
    var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
    el.id = id;
    el.className = 'el-alvo';
    el.innerHTML = id;
    container.appendChild(el);
});

function temClasse(elem, className) {
    return elem.className.split(' ').indexOf(className) > -1;
}
container.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (temClasse(e.target, 'el-alvo')) {
        alert(e.target.id);
    }
});
```

```css
.container li {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.container li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
    <li id="primeiro" class="el-alvo">primeiro</li>
    <li id="segundo" class="el-alvo">segundo</li>
    <li id="terceiro" class="el-alvo">terceiro</li>
</ul>
<button id="add-el" type="button">
Add li
</button>
```

> Mais sobre o `split()` aqui: [w3schools - split() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)
> Mais sobre o `indexOf()` aqui: [w3schools - indexOf() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

### Versão jQuery seria algo como:

Com jQuery seria algo mais curto como neste exemplo abaixo:

```js
// Código abaixo não interessa. Apenas para criar novos elementos
document.getElementById('add-el').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var el = document.createElement('li');
    el.className = "el-alvo";
    var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
    el.id = id;
    el.innerHTML = id;
    document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(el);
});

// com jQuery
$('.container').on('click', '.el-alvo', function(e) {
    alert(e.target.id);
});
```

```css
.container li {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.container li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
    <li id="first" class="el-alvo">first</li>
    <li id="second" class="el-alvo">second</li>
    <li id="third" class="el-alvo">third</li>
</ul>
<button id="add-el" type="button">
Add li
</button>
```

Comment: Acho que a resposta carece de explicações, principalmente de atribuir o evento ao documento e depois verificar o alvo.

Comment: Olá @Chun. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Funcionou certinho. Agora preciso ajustar a minha necessidade. Uma dúvida: Esta ação será disparada toda vez que um click for realizado, certo? Isso causa algum problema de performance?

Comment: @MatheusDelatorrre aprimorei a minha resposta no evento clique apontando apenas para o elemento alvo em vez de todo o documento, assim as iterações só serão feitas quando o especifico elemento for clicado 
e não todo o documento que seria uma verificação constante.

Comment: obrigado pelo feedback @AndersonCarlosWoss , fez-me também aperceber que o evento clique poderia ser melhorado =)

Comment: Obrigado @Chun. agora ficou mais claro.